# label and text field on same line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can someone take a look at the sample and help me to make label and input fields forizontal? Currently it is label and below it input fild. I need label:input field.

http://jsfiddle.net/dUG4f/4/

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                         <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Application Information</h3></div>
                         <div class="panel-body">

                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-6">
                                   <div class ="form-group">
                                        <label for="text" >Contract State</label>       
                                        <div class="input-group">    
                                            <select name="State" id="State" class="validate[required] form-control">
                                            <option value="">Choose a State</option>                    
                                            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                                            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                            </select>                                                       
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class ="form-group">
                                        <label for="text" >Application Number</label>       
                                         <div class="input-group">   
                                        <input  class="validate[required] text-input form-control" type="text" name="AppNumber" id="AppNumber" />                                           
                                        </div>   
                                    </div>                                      


                             </div> <!-- col-lg-6 col close -->
                            </div> <!-- row close -->
                         </div> <!--  End of panel Body -->     
                    </div><!--  End of panel  -->       
                </div> <!-- end col-xs-6 -->
```

How can I align labels righ and controls left with margin gap in between?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add class in label and give style: float left

```
<div class ="form-group">
     <label for="text" style="float:left;margin-right:5px;">Application Number</label>       
     <div class="input-group">   
     <input  class="validate[required] text-input form-control" type="text" name="AppNumber" id="AppNumber" />                                           
     </div>   
     </div>
```

Comment: This solution helped. Thank You!. Is there anway I ca napply this for entire <div class="row"> or <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-6">
so all the form groups below it will follow the same label:input pattern ?

Comment: yes you can give more class in a div seprated by space like <div class="selector1 selector2"></div>

Comment: I am sorry. I did not quite understand your answer. I mean to ask what if i want both dropdown and input should have lable and formcontrol on same line, then instead of applying this format for individual div's, can we apply at row or column level? Thanks!

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/dUG4f/10/ I guess you want like this and accept answer if it helps you.

Comment: Can I ask you anothe rquestion? How can I align labels and controls ? If I see in the fiddle they look odd to me.jsfiddle.net/dUG4f/10

Comment: simply define "width:138px;" or as per your requirement in .field class.

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap your form-group in a `form-inline` class like this:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class ="form-group">
    <label for="text" >Application Number</label>       
      <div class="input-group">   
        <input  class="validate[required] text-input form-control" type="text" name="AppNumber" id="AppNumber" />                                           
      </div>   
  </div>
</form>
```

P.S. the `form-inline` wrapper doesn't necessarily need to be a `form` tag so you can use a `div` tag too.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple solutions for you matter. For example:

```
<div style="width: 200px; float: left;">
    <label for="text">Application Number:</label>
</div>    
<div class="input-group" style="float:left;">   
    <input  class="validate[required] text-input form-control" type="text" name="AppNumber" id="AppNumber" />                                           
</div>
```

To multiple rows, it can be something like this:

```
<div style="width: 200px; float: left;">
    <label for="text">Field 1:</label>
</div>    
<div class="input-group" style="float:left;">   
    <input  class="validate[required] text-input form-control" type="text" name="AppNumber" id="AppNumber" />                                           
</div> 
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>

<div style="width: 200px; float: left;">
    <label for="text">Field 2:</label>
</div>    
<div class="input-group" style="float:left;">   
    <input  class="validate[required] text-input form-control" type="text" name="AppNumber" id="AppNumber" />                                           
</div> 
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>

<div style="width: 200px; float: left;">
    <label for="text">Field 3:</label>
</div>    
<div class="input-group" style="float:left;">   
    <input  class="validate[required] text-input form-control" type="text" name="AppNumber" id="AppNumber" />                                           
</div> 
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Can we have two class in one input field?

Comment: I have tried both solutions and did not work. Can you please take a look at the JSfiddle? Thanks!

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't see you had a "class" element

Comment: Thank you! Is there anyway I can apply this pattern at row or column level so all the form groups will follow it? <div class="row">or <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-6">

Comment: @user2088016 please, if our answer has been usefull for you, don't forget to validate them ;-), many thanks!